# Grass swing/shake effect in 2D game

Tags: opengl, c++, glsl

I want to make the grass swing/shake whenever the player walk through it. Like shown in this gif [Grass Swing Effect](https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/clans/27930497/b8d7285658b9a63e3d7a4ce91d0a1fcd7152d654.gif) from this [article](http://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/SvyatoslavCherkasov/20181023/329151/Graveyard_Keeper_How_the_graphics_effects_are_made.php).

I know I have to move the x coordinates of the vertices factored by y coordinates. But I'm not sure how to implement it?

Comment: Have you thought about using a 2D sprite frames technique?

Comment: I think the easiest way you could achieve this effect (as stated by TomTsagk) is by using [Sprites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animation) and then create a full animation using those frames.

You would need to create your animations frame by frame, in a drawing program, like Photoshop or Krita, and draw all the frames of your grass object moving. That's probably what the game's developers chose to do, since it would be  easier to manage and use in a game.